# Стираются значения из БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

При обновлении значения базы данных, старые значения переменных стираются. А нужно, чтобы они оставались. То есть при заполнении не всех полей, те, которые остались не заполнены обращаются в ноль

```
if (isset($_POST['rent'])) {
    $rent = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['rent'])));
    $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE price SET `rent` = '$rent' WHERE price.id=0");
}

if (isset($_POST['extra_rent'])) {
    $extra_rent = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['extra_rent'])));
    $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE price SET `extra_rent` = '$extra_rent' WHERE price.id=0");
}

if (isset($_POST['micro'])) {
    $micro = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['micro'])));
    $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE price SET `micro` = '$micro' WHERE price.id=0");
}

if (isset($_POST['flip'])) {
    $flip = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['flip'])));
    $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE price SET `flip` = '$flip' WHERE price.id=0");
}

if (isset($_POST['laptop'])) {
    $laptop = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['laptop'])));
    $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE price SET `laptop` = '$laptop' WHERE price.id=0");
}
```

Comment: Нашел ошибку, забыл проверить перед добавлением на пустоту

Comment: Неа, неправильно. во первых пора уже переходить на PDO (или mysqli на худой конец) и использовать привязываемые переменные. И тогда запрос придет к виду `UPDATE price SET rent=IFNULL(?,rent), flip=IFNULL(?,flip), ... ` и его execute с передачей пришедших на вход параметров виде массива. И замет строк 5 и будет при этом универсальным с легко добавляемыми полями